# Transforming data during replication

Tags: sql-server, ssis, replication, database-replication

I'm replicating some tables from a product that we're integrating with, into our own application's db. However, we'd like to make some transformations of the data at the same time - for example, alter some column data types and perhaps more advanced stuff like changing one-to-many relationships in to one-to-one and vice versa.

What options are available to implement this sort of thing?
We are using SQL Server 2008

Comment: You have tagged SSIS with your questions which lets me to believe that you know of something called `Data Flow Task`. Try [googling on that](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=transformations+ssis+data+flow+task+)

Comment: It's a rather broad question as it stands, think you could pare it down to something answerable? I'm a fan of SSIS for such things but you could do the same with TSQL and linked servers, PowerShell, other tools, etc

Comment: Yes, I've heard of SSIS but don't know anything about it and wasn't sure if it was overkill for this job on its own. The only other technique I've read about is customising the SPs that get used to insert, update and delete records in the target tables. I'm looking for simple solutions of course - something that doesn't take long to install, configure and get working with